# Project Showcase '14 Winners!

Tags: discussion, events

> [image]

Thanks to everyone for submitting a project to our first [Arduino Day Project Showcase](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/876/project-showcase-14). With 14 submissions we think it was a success! Here are the winners:

1. [Energy saver for the absent minded PC user](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/880/11) - [jippie](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/83/jippie)
2. [Stateful questbox](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/915/11) - [hithwen](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/754/hithwen)

**The winner (jippie) will receive an official Stack Exchange t-shirt and the runner up (hithwen) gets the 100 rep bounty.**

Congratulations to both winners! We would also like to thank everyone for participating!

Comment: Hope summer comes early this year ;o)